# How to show images in the place of label in black berry screen using eclips plugin

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I am developing one Blackberry application using Eclipse, I need to show images in the place of label like for example new button is there in the place of new button i need to show some image. How can i show images can you please give one example.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;

public class CustomButton extends Field {

    final Bitmap bitmap1;
    final Bitmap bitmap2;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    CustomButton() {
        bitmap1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_01.jpg");
        bitmap2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button_02.jpg");
        bitmap = bitmap1;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return bitmap1.getHeight();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return bitmap1.getWidth();
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), bitmap, 0, 0);
    }

    protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {
        try {
            getChangeListener().fieldChanged(this, context);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }
    }

    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {

        setExtent(Math.min(width, getPreferredWidth()), Math.min(height,
                getPreferredHeight()));
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        bitmap = bitmap2;
        invalidate();
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(1);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        bitmap = bitmap1;
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

and call like this

```
CustomButton button = new CustomButton(){
            protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {
                //button click
                super.fieldChangeNotify(context);
            }
        };
```

Comment: i need the image in the place of button when we click on image it will act as a button , how can we do this..